# How to run Parsec test in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Most recently, I've started learning parser implementation with Hackage libraries, particularly Parsec. So far I've this code to test integer addition as one of simple calculator features:

```
import Text.Parsec hiding(digit)
import Data.Functor

type Parser a = Parsec String () a

digit :: Parser Char
digit = oneOf ['0'..'9']

number :: Parser Integer
number = read <$> many1 digit

addition = do
    lhv <- number
    spaces
    char '+'
    spaces
    rhv <- number
    return $ lhv + rhv
```

I'm a little bit confused due to missing clue to start this parser by GHCI (my OS is Windows 10). What do I want to enter in command prompt just for having some test of that?

Comment: There's a tiny library I made that provides helpers for testing `parsec` parsers in the Hspec testing framework: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-parsec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `parseTest` function from the [Text.Parsec module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html). A sample session in GHCI:

```
~/g/scripts $ stack ghci parser.hs
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/sibi/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/sibi/github/scripts/parser.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/haskell-stack-ghci/452ad586/ghci-script
λ> :t addition
addition
  :: ParsecT String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Integer
λ> :t parseTest
parseTest
  :: (Stream s Data.Functor.Identity.Identity t, Show a) =>
     Parsec s () a -> s -> IO ()
λ> parseTest addition "3 + 2"
5
```